# Prestashop - Multi Shop Associations - Missing Group name

Tags: prestashop

Im making a multi shop module, the module saves / adds to the modules shop tables etc.

This part is fine.

I just have an issue with the GUI its missing the Group names, to me it looks like I'm missing something for a sprintf() I just see the %s and not the group name.

The image shows what I mean.

[image]

In my renderform function I have added.

```
if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) 
    {
        $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
            'type' => 'shop',
            'label' => $this->l('Shop association'),
            'name' => 'checkBoxShopAsso',
            'values' => Shop::getTree()
        );
    }
```

I wonder do i need to add anything else? all of the other modules I have look fine.

Thanks.

** Updated **

Have just found the template, it is the sprintf() that is not working because if i relace the line it works fine.

```
{*<label class="tree-toggler">{l s='Group: %s' sprintf=$node['name']}</label>*}
<label class="tree-toggler">{$node['name']}</label>
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be a translation related problem. Have a look at this translation in admin.

Comment: good call but I removed the translation which was - Group: %s its weird because this doesnt happen with the carriers module. Do know how to override the helper template?

Comment: you can try `/modules/your_module/override/controllers/admin/templates/helpers/tree/tree_node_folder_checkbox_shops.tpl` but didn't test it.

Comment: no - still not working, thanks for your help though